# Software for taking backup of files and folders in Java language

Tags: java

This is a software to take backups of file(s) and folders. This can save backups in a network folder also. This software can take successful backups of huge number of file(s)/folder(s). In one test, this software successfully copied 19,466 files. This software can be used by individuals as well by companies/enterprises.

Please review. The code is below.

---

### Backup_Files_And_Folders.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Backup_Files_And_Folders implements ActionListener {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    int midScreenWidth = screenWidth / 2;
    int midScreenHeight = screenHeight / 2;

    int componentHeight = 25;
    int vGap = 25; // vertical gap between components
    int hGap = 10; // horizontal gap between components
    int currentYPos = 0;

    JFrame jf = null;
    JPanel jp = null;
    JDialog jdShowRemoveFiles = null;
    JPanel jpShowRemoveFiles = null;
    JLabel jlInfoLabel = null;
    JButton jbAddFilesFolders = null;
    JButton jbShowRemoveFilesFolders = null;
    JLabel jlShowNumFiles = null;
    JButton jbRemoveAllEntries = null;
    JLabel jlChooseSaveBackupLocation = null;
    JTextField jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation = null;
    JButton jbBrowse = null;
    JButton jbTakeBackup = null;
    JButton jbCancelBackup = null;
    JLabel jlBackupProgressBarLabel = null;
    JProgressBar jpbBackupProgressBar = null;
    JLabel jlCurrentStatus = null;
    JTextArea jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea = null;
    JScrollPane jspScrollableExceptionTextArea = null;
    JButton jbCloseMainWindow = null;

    Color DeepSkyBlue = new Color(0x00bfff);

    String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String backupSoftwareConfigDir = userHomeDir + File.separator + "Backup_Files_And_Folders";
    String backupSoftwareConfigFile = backupSoftwareConfigDir + File.separator + "Config.txt";
    String fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup = backupSoftwareConfigDir + File.separator + "Files_Directories_To_Backup.txt";
    String backupDir = null;
    String logFile = null;
    Path logFilePath = null;

    boolean cancelBackup = false;

    LinkedList<String> listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<JLabel> listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<JButton> listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL = new LinkedList<>();

    public enum SetupStatus {
        DONE,
        NOT_DONE,
        CORRUPTED,
    } // end of enum SetupStatus

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        String text = "";

        Object source = ae.getSource();

        if (source == jbBrowse) {

            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            if ((jfc.showOpenDialog(jf)) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                backupDir = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation.setText(backupDir);

                // Put this path in config file also. Open file for writing in truncated mode.
                try {
                    Files.write(Paths.get(backupSoftwareConfigFile), selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    text = "Exception happened: Could not write to file \"" + backupSoftwareConfigFile + "\". Please check whether file exists and permissions of file.";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } // end of try-catch block

                // Create log file if not already existing.
                logFile = backupDir + File.separator + "log.txt";
                if (checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist(logFile) == true) {
                    logFilePath = Paths.get(logFile);
                }
            }

        } else if (source == jbAddFilesFolders) {

            boolean error = false;
            int filesAdded = 0;
            String lineToWrite = "";
            File selectedFiles[] = null;
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            if ((jfc.showOpenDialog(jf)) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedFiles = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
                // Append the file selected to file Files_Directories_To_Backup.txt.
                for (File f : selectedFiles) {
                    lineToWrite = f.getAbsolutePath() + System.lineSeparator();
                    try {
                        Files.write(Paths.get(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup), lineToWrite.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
                        filesAdded = filesAdded + 1;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        error = true;
                        text = "Exception happened: Could not write to file \"" + fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup + "\". Please check whether file exists and permissions of file.";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } // end of try-catch block
                } // end of for loop
                if ((filesAdded > 0) && (error == false)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "File(s) / Folder(s) added successfully.", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else if ((filesAdded > 0) && (error == true)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Some File(s) / Folder(s) added successfully.", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            } // end of jfc.showOpenDialog(jf)) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION

        } else if (source == jbShowRemoveFilesFolders) {

            processShowRemoveFilesFolders();

        } else if (source == jbRemoveAllEntries) { // this event is from JDialog

            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(jpShowRemoveFiles, "Are you sure you want to remove all entries?", "Question", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                Files.write(Paths.get(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup), new byte[0], StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                text = "Error: Exception happened while removing entries from file \"" + fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup + "\". Remove operation has been cancelled.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.clear();
            listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.clear();
            listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL.clear();

            jpShowRemoveFiles.removeAll();

            jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jlShowNumFiles);
            jlShowNumFiles.setText("Total File(s) / Folder(s): " + listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.size());
            jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jbRemoveAllEntries);

            jpShowRemoveFiles.revalidate();
            jpShowRemoveFiles.repaint();

        } else if ((((JButton) (source)).getText()).equals("Remove") == true) { // this event is from JDialog

            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, "Remove event from JDialog", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            int index = listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.indexOf(source);

            if (index == -1) {
                text = "Some bug in software because returned index is -1. This should not be the case.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            String tmpFile = backupSoftwareConfigDir + File.separator + ".tmpFile";
            boolean status = removeLineFromFileAtIndex(index, fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup, tmpFile);

            if (status == true) {
                // now remove the entry from jdialog's jpanel and from all linked lists.
                jpShowRemoveFiles.remove(listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.get(index));
                jpShowRemoveFiles.remove(listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL.get(index));
                listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.remove(index);
                listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.remove(index);
                listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL.remove(index);
                jpShowRemoveFiles.revalidate();
                jpShowRemoveFiles.repaint();
                jlShowNumFiles.setText("Total File(s) / Folder(s): " + listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.size());
            }

            return;

        } else if (source == jbTakeBackup) {

            // we need to start a new thread for this so that UI can be updated because UI update
            // events will come on this thread (event thread) itself but this thread is already processing
            // processTakeBackup(), so UI update events wait in the queue for processTakeBackup() to finish.
            // So, we don't see any UI updates while processTakeBackup() is running but we want to see UI
            // updates while processTakeBackup() is running and so we have to run processTakeBackup() in a new thread.
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    processTakeBackup();
                }
            }; // end of new thread

            thread.start();

        } else if (source == jbCancelBackup) {

            cancelBackup = true;

        } else if (source == jbCloseMainWindow) {

            jf.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(jf, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));

        }

    } // end of actionPerformed

    void processShowRemoveFilesFolders() {

        int numEntries = 0;
        String line = null;
        String text = null;

        // clear all linkedlists (delete all elements from all linkedlists)
        listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.clear();
        listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.clear();
        listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL.clear();

        // we need to save entries from fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup in a linkedlist.
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                // no need to remove newline characters. readLine already removes them.
                //line = line.replaceFirst("\\r\\n$|\\r$|\\n$", "");

                listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.add(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            text = "Exception happened: Could not read file \"" + fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup + "\": " + e.getMessage();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            return; // we do not want to show anything now as exception has happened.

        } // end of try-catch block

        numEntries = listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL.size();

        int dialogWidth = (int) (screenWidth * (0.775));
        int dialogHeight = (int) (screenHeight * (0.56));
        int panelWidth = 10 + 100 + 10 + 1024 + 10;
        int panelHeight = 35 * numEntries + 35 + 10;

        ArrayList<Object> a = SwingLibrary.setupScrollableJDialogAndGetDialogAndPanel(jf, "List of Files for backing up", true, dialogWidth, dialogHeight, panelWidth, panelHeight);
        jdShowRemoveFiles = (JDialog) (a.get(0));
        jpShowRemoveFiles = (JPanel) (a.get(1));

        // show list of files for backing up
        JLabel jl = null;
        JButton jb = null;
        int xPos = 10;
        int yPos = 10;

        // show total file(s) / folder(s)
        text = "Total File(s) / Folder(s): " + numEntries;
        jlShowNumFiles = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet(text, true, Color.WHITE, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, xPos, yPos, 300, componentHeight);
        jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jlShowNumFiles);

        // implement remove all entries here
        jbRemoveAllEntries = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Remove All Entries", this, true, xPos + 350, yPos, 300, componentHeight);
        yPos = yPos + 25 + 10;
        jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jbRemoveAllEntries);

        for (String s : listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLL) {

            //System.out.println(s);
            xPos = 10;
            jb = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Remove", this, true, xPos, yPos, 100, componentHeight);
            xPos = xPos + 110;
            jl = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet(s, true, Color.WHITE, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, xPos, yPos, 1024, componentHeight);
            yPos = yPos + 25 + 10;
            listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupButtonsLL.add(jb);
            listOfFilesAndFoldersToBackupLabelsLL.add(jl);
            jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jb);
            jpShowRemoveFiles.add(jl);

        } // end of for loop

        jdShowRemoveFiles.setVisible(true);

    } // end of processShowRemoveFilesFolders
    
    // If append is true then append text, else truncate the file.
    void writeToLogFile(String text, OpenOption op) {

        if (logFilePath == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            text = text + System.lineSeparator();
            Files.write(logFilePath, text.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, op, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    } // end of writeToLogFile

    void processCancelBackup() {

        // write trailer in log file
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + "Backup Cancelled.", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + "=============== Backup Cancelled ===============", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        jlCurrentStatus.setForeground(Color.RED);
        jlCurrentStatus.setText("Backup Cancelled.                    You can look at log file at location: " + logFile);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Backup Cancelled.", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // the following method sets cancelBackup to false.
        enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();

    } // end of processCancelBackup

    void enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel() {

        cancelBackup = false;
        jbCancelBackup.setEnabled(false);
        jbAddFilesFolders.setEnabled(true);
        jbShowRemoveFilesFolders.setEnabled(true);
        jbBrowse.setEnabled(true);
        jbTakeBackup.setEnabled(true);

    } // end of enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel

    void disableComponentsAndEnableCancelOnBackupStart() {

        jbTakeBackup.setEnabled(false);
        jbBrowse.setEnabled(false);
        jbAddFilesFolders.setEnabled(false);
        jbShowRemoveFilesFolders.setEnabled(false);
        jbCancelBackup.setEnabled(true);

    } // end of disableComponentsAndEnableCancelOnBackupStart

    long copyDirectoryRecursively(String sourceDir, String destDir, long numFilesCopied, long totalFilesCount) {

        String entryAsString = null;
        String targetFileOrDir = null;
        String text = null;

        try {
            text = "Creating directory: " + destDir;
            jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
            writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

            Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(destDir));

            // write in log file and update current status label
            text = "Created directory: " + destDir;
            jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
            writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
            text = "** Exception happened while creating directory \"" + destDir + "\": Directory \"" + destDir + "\" already exists: " + faee.getMessage();
            writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
            jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
            return numFilesCopied;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            text = "** Exception happened while creating directory \"" + destDir + "\": " + e.getMessage();
            writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
            jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
            return numFilesCopied;
        }

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(sourceDir))) {

            for (Path entry : ds) {

                if (cancelBackup == true) {
                    try {
                        ds.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return numFilesCopied;
                }

                entryAsString = entry.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                targetFileOrDir = destDir + File.separator + entryAsString.substring(entryAsString.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);

                if (Files.isRegularFile(entry) == true) {
                    try {
                        text = "Copying file " + entryAsString + " to " + targetFileOrDir;
                        jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                        writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

                        Files.copy(entry, Paths.get(targetFileOrDir), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                        numFilesCopied = numFilesCopied + 1;

                        // write in log file and update current status label
                        text = "Copied file " + entryAsString + " to " + targetFileOrDir;
                        jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                        writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

                        jlBackupProgressBarLabel.setText("Backup Progress (Files backed up: " + numFilesCopied + " / " + totalFilesCount + ")");
                        jpbBackupProgressBar.setValue((int) ((numFilesCopied * 100) / totalFilesCount));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        text = "** Exception happened while copying \"" + entry.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\" to \"" + targetFileOrDir + "\": " + e.getMessage();
                        writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                        jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
                        jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                    }
                } else if (Files.isDirectory(entry) == true) {
                    numFilesCopied = copyDirectoryRecursively(entryAsString, targetFileOrDir, numFilesCopied, totalFilesCount);
                }

            } // end of for Path entry : ds

        } catch (Exception e) {

            text = "** Exception happened while processing directory \"" + sourceDir + "\": " + e.getMessage();
            writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
            jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);

        }

        return numFilesCopied;

    } // end of copyDirectoryRecursively

    long getNumberOfFilesAndDirsInDir(Path p, long totalFilesCount) {

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(p)) {

            for (Path entry : ds) {
                if (cancelBackup == true) {
                    try {
                        ds.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return totalFilesCount;
                }
                if (Files.isRegularFile(entry) == true) {
                    totalFilesCount = totalFilesCount + 1;
                    jlCurrentStatus.setText("Counting number of files to be backed up: " + totalFilesCount);
                } else if (Files.isDirectory(entry) == true) {
                    totalFilesCount = getNumberOfFilesAndDirsInDir(entry, totalFilesCount);
                    jlCurrentStatus.setText("Counting number of files to be backed up: " + totalFilesCount);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        } // end of try-catch block

        return totalFilesCount;

    } // end of getNumberOfFilesAndDirsInDir

    void processBackupNotTaken(String text) {

        // write trailer to log file
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + "=============== End ===============", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
        jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    } // end of processBackupNotTaken

    void processTakeBackup() {

        disableComponentsAndEnableCancelOnBackupStart();

        String text = null;
        String targetBackupDir = null;
        Path p = null;
        boolean firstTime = true;
        boolean someFileOrFolderExists = false;

        LocalDateTime currentLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = null;

        // reset few things
        writeToLogFile("", StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.setText(null);
        jlCurrentStatus.setForeground(null);
        jlCurrentStatus.setText("Backup Process Started");
        jlBackupProgressBarLabel.setText("Backup Progress: Backup Process Started.");
        jpbBackupProgressBar.setValue(0);

        // write header and date/time to log file.
        writeToLogFile("=============== Backup Process Started ===============" + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        try {
            dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd LLL yyyy, hh:mm:ss a");
            writeToLogFile("Date/Time: " + currentLocalDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } // end of try-catch block

        // check if backup directory is given or not
        if (backupDir.isBlank() == true) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: Directory where backups will be saved is not given. No backup will be taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        }

        // check if backup directory exists
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(backupDir)) == false) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: Backup directory \"" + backupDir + "\" does not exist or may be permissions issue. No backup will be taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        }

        // we need to save entries from fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup in an array list.
        ArrayList<String> filesFoldersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                filesFoldersArrayList.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: Exception happened: Could not read file \"" + fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup + "\": " + e.getMessage() + ". No backup will be taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        } // end of try-catch block

        // if there are no files/folders to backup then show a message and return
        if (filesFoldersArrayList.isEmpty() == true) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: No file(s) / folder(s) have been added for backup. Nothing to backup.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        }

        // check which file(s)/folder(s) present in fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup do not exist.
        for (String fileOrDir : filesFoldersArrayList) {

            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

            p = Paths.get(fileOrDir);

            if (Files.exists(p) == false) { // file/directory does not exist
                text = "Error: File/Folder does not exist: " + p.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
                jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
            } else {
                someFileOrFolderExists = true;
            }

            // processing cancelBackup here is necessary because it is possible that the
            // for loop has already consumed the last entry in filesFoldersArrayList,
            // so when now the control goes back to the for loop, it will not enter the loop
            // because there are no more entries to be read from filesFoldersArrayList and
            // hence it will come out of for loop and "cancelBackup == true" condition will
            // never hit.
            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

        } // end of for (String fileOrDir : filesFoldersArrayList)

        if (someFileOrFolderExists == false) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: No File(s)/Folder(s) given for backup exist. No backup has been taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        }

        // count total number of files for progress bar
        long totalFilesCount = 0;
        for (String dirOrFile : filesFoldersArrayList) {

            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

            p = Paths.get(dirOrFile);

            if (Files.isRegularFile(p) == true) {
                totalFilesCount = totalFilesCount + 1;
                jlCurrentStatus.setText("Counting number of files to be backed up: " + totalFilesCount);
            } else if (Files.isDirectory(p) == true) {
                totalFilesCount = getNumberOfFilesAndDirsInDir(p, totalFilesCount);
                jlCurrentStatus.setText("Counting number of files to be backed up: " + totalFilesCount);
            }

            // processing cancelBackup here is necessary because it is possible that the
            // for loop has already consumed the last entry in filesFoldersArrayList,
            // so when now the control goes back to the for loop, it will not enter the loop
            // because there are no more entries to be read from filesFoldersArrayList and
            // hence it will come out of for loop and "cancelBackup == true" condition will
            // never hit.
            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

        } // end of for (String dirOrFile : filesFoldersArrayList)
        
        // create directory where backups will be saved.
        try {
            dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyLLLdd-HH-mm-ss");
            targetBackupDir = backupDir + File.separator + "Backup-" + currentLocalDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: Exception happened: Could not get current date and time in desired format: " + e.getMessage() + ". No backup will be taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        } // end of try-catch block

        // debug
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Target Backup Dir: " + targetBackupDir, "Target Backup Dir", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        // create new directories if they don't exist
        if (checkAndCreateDirectoryIfItDoesNotExist(targetBackupDir) == false) {
            processBackupNotTaken("Error: Exception happened: Could not create directory \"" + targetBackupDir + "\". Please check permissions of directory \"" + backupDir + "\". No backup will be taken.");
            enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();
            return;
        }

        // start taking backup of files and folders
        long numFilesCopied = 0;
        String targetFileOrDir = null;
        String transformSourceFileOrDir = null;

        jlBackupProgressBarLabel.setText("Backup Progress (Files backed up: " + numFilesCopied + " / " + totalFilesCount + ")");
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + "Backup is being taken in directory: " + targetBackupDir + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        for (String sourceFileOrDir : filesFoldersArrayList) {

            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

            p = Paths.get(sourceFileOrDir);

            // transform source directory to full path
            if (Files.isDirectory(p) == true) {
                transformSourceFileOrDir = sourceFileOrDir.replace(File.separator, "-");
                transformSourceFileOrDir = transformSourceFileOrDir.replace(":", ""); // to fix C:\AAA\BBB, etc.
                targetFileOrDir = targetBackupDir + File.separator + transformSourceFileOrDir;
            } else {
                targetFileOrDir = targetBackupDir + File.separator + sourceFileOrDir.substring(sourceFileOrDir.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
            }

            if (Files.isRegularFile(p) == true) {
                try {
                    // write in log file and update current status label
                    text = "Copying file " + sourceFileOrDir + " to " + targetFileOrDir;
                    jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                    writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

                    Files.copy(p, Paths.get(targetFileOrDir), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                    numFilesCopied = numFilesCopied + 1;

                    // write in log file and update current status label
                    text = "Copied file " + sourceFileOrDir + " to " + targetFileOrDir;
                    jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                    writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

                    jlBackupProgressBarLabel.setText("Backup Progress (Files backed up: " + numFilesCopied + " / " + totalFilesCount + ")");
                    jpbBackupProgressBar.setValue((int) ((numFilesCopied * 100) / totalFilesCount));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    text = "** Exception happened while copying \"" + p.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\" to \"" + targetFileOrDir + "\": " + e.getMessage();
                    writeToLogFile(text, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                    jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea.append(text + "\n");
                    jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);
                }
            } else if (Files.isDirectory(p) == true) {
                numFilesCopied = copyDirectoryRecursively(sourceFileOrDir, targetFileOrDir, numFilesCopied, totalFilesCount);
            }

            // print an empty line after each entry is processed
            writeToLogFile("", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

            // processing cancelBackup here is necessary because it is possible that the
            // for loop has already consumed the last entry in filesFoldersArrayList,
            // so when now the control goes back to the for loop, it will not enter the loop
            // because there are no more entries to be read from filesFoldersArrayList and
            // hence it will come out of for loop and "cancelBackup == true" condition will
            // never hit.
            if (cancelBackup == true) {
                processCancelBackup();
                return;
            }

        } // end of for (String sourceFileOrDir : filesFoldersArrayList)

        // write trailer in log file
        writeToLogFile(System.lineSeparator() + "=============== End of Backup ===============", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        text = "Backup taken in directory \"" + targetBackupDir + "\".";
        text = text + "                    You can look at log file at location: " + logFile;
        jlCurrentStatus.setText(text);

        text = "Backup taken in directory \"" + targetBackupDir + "\".";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // the following method sets cancelBackup to false.
        enableComponentsAndDisableCancelOnBackupEndOrBackupCancel();

    } // end of processTakeBackup

    boolean removeLineFromFileAtIndex(int index, String file, String tmpFile) {

        String text = null;
        String line = null;
        boolean lineFound = false;
        int i = -1;

        if (index < 0) {
            text = "Index given is invalid: It is less than zero: " + index;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

        try (
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(tmpFile), false);) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                // increment i
                i = i + 1;
                if (index == i) {
                    lineFound = true;
                    continue;
                }
                fw.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
                fw.flush();
            } // end of while

            br.close();
            fw.close();

            Files.move(Paths.get(tmpFile), Paths.get(file), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            try {
                // delete temp file
                Files.delete(Paths.get(tmpFile));
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }

            text = "Exception happened: " + e.getMessage();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            return false;

        } // end of try-catch block

        if (lineFound == false) {
            text = "No line found at given Index. Index given: " + index;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jdShowRemoveFiles, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    } // end of removeLineFromFileAtIndex

    boolean checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist(String file) {

        try {
            Files.createFile(Paths.get(file));
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
            // don't do anything. file exists.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    } // end of checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist

    boolean checkAndCreateDirectoryIfItDoesNotExist(String dir) {

        try {
            Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(dir));
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
            // don't do anything. directory exists.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    } // end of checkAndCreateDirectoryIfItDoesNotExist

    // Create required files and directories if they don't exist.
    void doSetup(SetupStatus ss) {

        String text = "";
        int result = -1;

        if (ss == SetupStatus.NOT_DONE) {
            text = "Setup is not done. Setup will create a directory in \"" + userHomeDir + "\" and then create "
                    + "some files inside the new directory. Do you want to continue doing setup?";
        } else {
            text = "Setup is corrupted. Do you want to fix setup?";
        }

        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(jf, text, "Question", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Exiting..", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // create files and directories if they don't exist
        if (checkAndCreateDirectoryIfItDoesNotExist(backupSoftwareConfigDir) == false) {
            text = "Exception happened: Could not create directory \"" + backupSoftwareConfigDir + "\". Please check permissions of directory \"" + userHomeDir + "\". Exiting..";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist(backupSoftwareConfigFile) == false) {
            text = "Exception happened: Could not create file \"" + backupSoftwareConfigFile + "\". Please check permissions of directory \"" + backupSoftwareConfigDir + "\". Exiting..";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup) == false) {
            text = "Exception happened: Could not create file \"" + fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup + "\". Please check permissions of directory \"" + backupSoftwareConfigDir + "\". Exiting..";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (ss == SetupStatus.NOT_DONE) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Setup done successfully.", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Setup fixed successfully.", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    } // end of doSetup

    // Check that required files and directories exist.
    SetupStatus checkSetupDone() {

        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(backupSoftwareConfigDir)) == false) {
            return SetupStatus.NOT_DONE;
        }

        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(backupSoftwareConfigFile)) == false) {
            return SetupStatus.CORRUPTED;
        }

        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(fileContainingNamesOfFilesDirectoriesToBackup)) == false) {
            return SetupStatus.CORRUPTED;
        }

        return SetupStatus.DONE;

    } // end of checkSetupDone

    void doSetupAndCreateAndShowGUI() {

        String text = "";
        JLabel jl = null;

        ArrayList<Object> a = SwingLibrary.setupScrollableJFrameAndGetFrameAndPanel("Backup Files And Folders", screenWidth - 10, screenHeight - 50);
        jf = (JFrame) (a.get(0));
        jp = (JPanel) (a.get(1));
        jf.setVisible(true);

        // check if setup is done or not. If not, then do the setup.
        SetupStatus ss = checkSetupDone();
        if (ss != SetupStatus.DONE) {
            doSetup(ss);
        }

        currentYPos = 0;
        text = "<html><p style=\"text-align:center;\">"
                + "Backups will be saved in a directory named as Backup_Date_Time in the directory you have chosen for saving backups.<br><br>"
                + "In Backup_Date_Time, Date is the date on which the backup has been taken and Time is the time at which the backup has been taken.<br><br>"
                + "A log file is created in the directory Backup_Date_Time and it will contain details of last backup only (including all exceptions if they happened).<br>"
                + "</p></html>";
        jlInfoLabel = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet(text, true, DeepSkyBlue, SwingConstants.CENTER, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 0, currentYPos, screenWidth, componentHeight * 4);
        jp.add(jlInfoLabel);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 6;
        jbAddFilesFolders = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("ADD file(s) / folder(s) for backing up", this, true, midScreenWidth - 500, currentYPos, 350, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jbAddFilesFolders);

        jbShowRemoveFilesFolders = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("SHOW / REMOVE file(s) / folder(s) added for backing up", this, true, midScreenWidth + 150, currentYPos, 350, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jbShowRemoveFilesFolders);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 3;
        jlChooseSaveBackupLocation = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet("Choose a directory where backups will be saved:", true, null, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 25, currentYPos, 300, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jlChooseSaveBackupLocation);
        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap;
        jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation = SwingLibrary.setupJTextFieldAndGet(25, currentYPos, screenWidth - 180, componentHeight);
        jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation.setEditable(false);
        jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        jp.add(jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation);
        jbBrowse = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Browse", this, true, screenWidth - 140, currentYPos, 100, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jbBrowse);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 3;
        jbTakeBackup = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Take Backup", this, true, midScreenWidth - 400, currentYPos, 200, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jbTakeBackup);

        //currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 3;
        jbCancelBackup = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Cancel Backup", this, true, midScreenWidth + 200, currentYPos, 200, componentHeight);
        jbCancelBackup.setEnabled(false);
        jp.add(jbCancelBackup);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 2;
        jlBackupProgressBarLabel = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet("Backup Progress: Not Started.", false, null, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 25, currentYPos, 500, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jlBackupProgressBarLabel);
        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap;
        jpbBackupProgressBar = SwingLibrary.setupJProgressBarAndGet(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 0, true, true, true, 25, currentYPos, screenWidth - 80, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jpbBackupProgressBar);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 2;
        jl = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet("Current Status:", false, null, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 25, currentYPos, 100, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jl);
        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap;
        jlCurrentStatus = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet("", false, null, SwingConstants.CENTER, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 25, currentYPos, screenWidth - 80, componentHeight);
        jlCurrentStatus.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        jp.add(jlCurrentStatus);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 2;
        jl = SwingLibrary.setupJLabelAndGet("Exceptions and Errors:", false, null, SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER, true, 25, currentYPos, 200, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jl);
        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap;
        jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea = SwingLibrary.setupJTextAreaAndGet("", 100, 225, false, true, true, false, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        jspScrollableExceptionTextArea = SwingLibrary.setupScrollableJTextAreaAndGet(jtaExceptionsAndErrorsTextArea, 25, currentYPos, screenWidth - 80, componentHeight * 7);
        jp.add(jspScrollableExceptionTextArea);

        currentYPos = currentYPos + vGap * 8;
        jbCloseMainWindow = SwingLibrary.setupJButtonAndGet("Close Main Window", this, true, midScreenWidth - 100, currentYPos, 200, componentHeight);
        jp.add(jbCloseMainWindow);

        jp.revalidate();
        jp.repaint();

        // Check if there is some path saved in backupSoftwareConfigFile. If yes, then set the text field jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation to that path.
        try {

            byte[] allBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(backupSoftwareConfigFile));

            // check that "\n" appended at the end of file name results in exception
            //byte[] allBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(backupSoftwareConfigFile + "\n"));

            backupDir = new String(allBytes);
            jtfChooseSaveBackupLocation.setText(backupDir);

            // Create log file if not already existing.
            logFile = backupDir + File.separator + "log.txt";
            if (checkAndCreateFileIfItDoesNotExist(logFile) == true) {
                logFilePath = Paths.get(logFile);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            text = "Exception happened: Could not read file \"" + backupSoftwareConfigFile + "\": " + e.getMessage();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, text, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } // end of try-catch block

    } // end of doSetupAndCreateAndShowGUI

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Backup_Files_And_Folders bfaf = new Backup_Files_And_Folders();
        bfaf.doSetupAndCreateAndShowGUI();

    } // end of main

} // end of Backup_Files_And_Folders

class SwingLibrary {

    // if width is 0 then the frame is maximized horizontally
    // if height is 0 then the frame is maximized vertically
    public static JFrame setupJFrameAndGet(String title, int width, int height) {
        int state = 0;
        JFrame tmpJF = new JFrame(title);
        if (width == 0) {
            state = state | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ;
        }
        if (height == 0) {
            state = state | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT;
        }
        if ((width != 0) || (height != 0)) {
            tmpJF.setSize(width, height);
        }
        tmpJF.setExtendedState(tmpJF.getExtendedState() | state);
        tmpJF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJF.setLayout(null);
        tmpJF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return tmpJF;
    } // end of setupJFrameAndGet

    // width and height are the preferred width and height of JPanel
    public static ArrayList<Object> setupScrollableJFrameAndGetFrameAndPanel(String title, int width, int height) {
        JFrame tmpJF = new JFrame(title);
        tmpJF.setExtendedState(tmpJF.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        tmpJF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //tmpJF.setLayout(null);

        JPanel tmpJP = new JPanel();
        //tmpJP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width + 1000, height + 1000);
        tmpJP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        tmpJP.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane tmpJSPFrame = new JScrollPane(tmpJP, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        tmpJSPFrame.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
        tmpJSPFrame.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
        tmpJF.add(tmpJSPFrame);

        ArrayList<Object> tmpA = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJF));
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJP));

        return tmpA;
    } // end of setupScrollableJFrameAndGetFrameAndPanel

    // actLisObj: object which implements action listener
    public static JButton setupJButtonAndGet(String text, Object actLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JButton tmpJB = new JButton(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJB.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        return tmpJB;
    } // end of setupJButtonAndGet

    // halign: horizontal alignment of text, valign: vertical alignment of text
    public static JLabel setupJLabelAndGet(String text, boolean opaque, Color bg, int halign, int valign, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JLabel tmpJL = new JLabel(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJL.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJL.setOpaque(opaque);
        if (bg != null) {
            tmpJL.setBackground(bg);
        }
        tmpJL.setHorizontalAlignment(halign);
        tmpJL.setVerticalAlignment(valign);
        return tmpJL;
    } // end of setupJlabelAndGet

    public static JTextField setupJTextFieldAndGet(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTextField tmpJTF = new JTextField();
        tmpJTF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJTF;
    } // end of setupJTextFieldAndGet

    public static JFormattedTextField setupJFormattedTextFieldAndGet(Format fmt, Object initialVal, Object propertyChangeLis, String propertyToListenFor, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JFormattedTextField tmpJFTF = new JFormattedTextField(fmt);
        tmpJFTF.setValue(initialVal);
        tmpJFTF.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyToListenFor, (PropertyChangeListener) propertyChangeLis);
        tmpJFTF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJFTF;
    } // end of setupJFormattedTextFieldAndGet

    // itemLisObj: object which implements item listener
    public static JCheckBox setupJCheckBoxAndGet(String text, boolean state, Object itemLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JCheckBox tmpJCB = new JCheckBox(text, state);
        tmpJCB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        tmpJCB.addItemListener((ItemListener) itemLisObj);
        return tmpJCB;
    } // end of setupJCheckBoxAndGet

    // actLisObj: object which implements action listener
    public static JRadioButton setupJRadioButtonAndGet(String text, boolean state, Object actLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JRadioButton tmpJRB = new JRadioButton(text, state);
        tmpJRB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        tmpJRB.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        return tmpJRB;
    } // end of setupJRadioButtonAndGet

    public static ButtonGroup setupButtonGroupAndGet() {
        ButtonGroup tmpBG = new ButtonGroup();
        return tmpBG;
    } // end of setupButtonGroupAndGet

    public static JPasswordField setupJPasswordFieldAndGet(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JPasswordField tmpJPF = new JPasswordField();
        tmpJPF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJPF;
    } // end of setupJPasswordFieldAndGet

    public static JTextArea setupJTextAreaAndGet(String text, int rows, int columns, boolean setEditableFlag, boolean setLineWrapFlag, boolean setWrapStyleWordFlag, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTextArea tmpJTA = new JTextArea(text, rows, columns);
        tmpJTA.setEditable(setEditableFlag);
        tmpJTA.setLineWrap(setLineWrapFlag);
        tmpJTA.setWrapStyleWord(setWrapStyleWordFlag);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTA.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJTA;
    } // end of setupJTextAreaAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJTextAreaAndGet(JTextArea jta, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jta);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJTextAreaAndGet

    public static JList<String> setupJListAndGet(ListModel<String> lm, int selectionMode, int visibleRowCount, int initialSelectedIndex, Object listSelLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JList<String> tmpJList = new JList<String>(lm);
        tmpJList.setSelectionMode(selectionMode);
        tmpJList.setVisibleRowCount(visibleRowCount);
        if (initialSelectedIndex >= 0) {
            tmpJList.setSelectedIndex(initialSelectedIndex);
        }
        tmpJList.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionListener) listSelLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJList.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJList;
    } // end of setupJListAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJListAndGet(JList jlist, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jlist);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJListAndGet

    public static JComboBox<String> setupJComboBoxAndGet(ComboBoxModel<String> cbm, int initialSelectedIndex, Object actLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JComboBox<String> tmpJComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(cbm);
        if (initialSelectedIndex >= 0) {
            tmpJComboBox.setSelectedIndex(initialSelectedIndex);
        }
        tmpJComboBox.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJComboBox.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJComboBox;
    } // end of setupJComboBoxAndGet

    public static JProgressBar setupJProgressBarAndGet(int orientation, int min, int max, int initialVal, boolean borderPaintedFlag, boolean stringPaintedFlag, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JProgressBar tmpJPB = new JProgressBar(orientation, min, max);
        tmpJPB.setValue(initialVal);
        tmpJPB.setBorderPainted(borderPaintedFlag);
        tmpJPB.setStringPainted(stringPaintedFlag);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJPB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJPB;
    } // end of setupJProgressBarAndGet

    public static JSlider setupJSliderAndGet(int orientation, int min, int max, int initialVal, int minorTickSpacing, int majorTickSpacing, boolean paintTicksFlag, boolean paintLabelsFlag, Object changeLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSlider tmpJS = new JSlider(orientation, min, max, initialVal);
        tmpJS.setMinorTickSpacing(minorTickSpacing);
        tmpJS.setMajorTickSpacing(majorTickSpacing);
        tmpJS.setPaintTicks(paintTicksFlag);
        tmpJS.setPaintLabels(paintLabelsFlag);
        tmpJS.addChangeListener((ChangeListener) changeLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJS.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJS;
    } // end of setupJSliderAndGet

    public static JTree setupJTreeAndGet(DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode, int selectionMode, Object treeSelLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTree tmpJTree = new JTree(rootNode);
        tmpJTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(selectionMode);
        tmpJTree.addTreeSelectionListener((TreeSelectionListener) treeSelLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTree.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJTree;
    } // end of setupJTreeAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJTreeAndGet(JTree jtree, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jtree);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJTreeAndGet

    public static JSpinner setupJSpinnerAndGet(SpinnerModel sm, boolean editableFlag, Object spinnerChangeLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSpinner tmpJSPN = new JSpinner(sm);
        tmpJSPN.addChangeListener((ChangeListener) spinnerChangeLisObj);
        if (editableFlag == false) {
            JComponent editor = tmpJSPN.getEditor();
            if (editor instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor) {
                ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField().setEditable(editableFlag);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Could not set editableFlag for JSpinner.");
            }
        }
        tmpJSPN.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSPN;
    } // end of setupJSpinnerAndGet

    public static JColorChooser setupJColorChooserAndGet(Color initialColor, boolean borderTitleFlag, String borderTitle, Object colorChooserChangeLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JColorChooser tmpJCC = new JColorChooser(initialColor);
        tmpJCC.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener((ChangeListener) colorChooserChangeLisObj);
        if (borderTitleFlag == true) {
            tmpJCC.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(borderTitle));
        }
        tmpJCC.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJCC;
    } // end of setupJColorChooserAndGet

    public static JDialog setupJDialogAndGet(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, int width, int height) {
        JDialog tmpJD = new JDialog(owner, title, modal);
        tmpJD.setSize(width, height);
        tmpJD.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJD.setLayout(null);
        tmpJD.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        return tmpJD;
    } // end of setupJDialogAndGet

    public static ArrayList<Object> setupScrollableJDialogAndGetDialogAndPanel(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, int dialogWidth, int dialogHeight, int panelWidth, int panelHeight) {
        JDialog tmpJD = new JDialog(owner, title, modal);
        tmpJD.setSize(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
        tmpJD.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJD.setLayout(null);
        tmpJD.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel tmpJP = new JPanel();
        tmpJP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelWidth, panelHeight));
        tmpJP.setLayout(null);

        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(ScrollPane.SCROLLBARS_ALWAYS);
        sp.add(tmpJP);
        tmpJD.getRootPane().setContentPane(sp);

        ArrayList<Object> tmpA = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJD));
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJP));

        return tmpA;
    } // end of setupJDialogAndGet

    public static JToggleButton setupJToggleButtonAndGet(String text, Object itemLisObj, boolean opaque, Color bgcolor, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JToggleButton tmpJTB = new JToggleButton(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJTB.addItemListener((ItemListener) itemLisObj);
        tmpJTB.setOpaque(opaque);
        tmpJTB.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJTB;
    } // end of setupJToggleButtonAndGet

    public static JSeparator setupJSeparatorAndGet(int orientation, Color bgcolor, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSeparator tmpJS = new JSeparator(orientation);
        tmpJS.setBackground(bgcolor);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJS.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJS;
    } // end of setupJSeparatorAndGet

    public static JMenuBar setupJMenuBarAndGet(Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenuBar tmpJMB = new JMenuBar();
        tmpJMB.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJMB.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJMB.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJMB;
    } // end of setupJMenuBarAndGet

    public static JMenu setupJMenuAndGet(String text, Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenu tmpJM = new JMenu(text);
        tmpJM.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJM.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJM.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJM;
    } // end of setupJMenuAndGet

    public static JMenuItem setupJMenuItemAndGet(String text, Object actLisObj, KeyStroke k, Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenuItem tmpJMI = new JMenuItem(text);
        tmpJMI.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJMI.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJMI.setBackground(bgcolor);
        tmpJMI.setAccelerator(k);
        if (actLisObj != null) {
            tmpJMI.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        }
        return tmpJMI;
    } // end of setupJMenuItemAndGet

} // end of SwingLibrary
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for something that appears to be a small function. Can you tell us more about what prompted you to write this code? A lot of it appears to be part of the GUI, but it's still quite lengthy. Is there any reason you didn't use more functions, to keep your functions smaller?

Comment: The main function in this program is copyDirectoryRecursively(). Rest of it is almost all GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be copying coding conventions from a language you learned before Java. Namely naming conventions and declaring all local variables in the beginning of methods regardless of their intended scope of use. You should try to follow the common [Java coding conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-introduction.html).

Do not do wildcard imports. Always include only the exact classes that you need. Mainly because it clearly indicates to the reader what exact classes you are using. A secondary benefit is that hundreds of include statementes indicate that your class has become too large. *In this case it has.*

You have absolutely to much code to be reviewed. Split the UI code into separate classes from "business logic". Study the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). In my opinion it is one of the most important things you can learn in programming. When you have done that, you can request a code review for just the classes that implement the file copying logic.

Comment: I will fix wild card imports.

Comment: Have you read the Java coding conventions? It supports my style of declaring variables at the beginning of a method. From the link that you gave, here is the excerpt - 6.3 -
Put declarations only at the beginning of blocks. (A block is any code surrounded by curly braces "{" and "}".) Don't wait to declare variables until their first use; it can confuse the unwary programmer and hamper code portability within the scope.

Comment: @Amit You have misinterpreted that document. "Method" and "code block" are not synonyms. A method is a code block but so are if-statements, for-loops and try-catch statements, for example. A code block is a piece of code surrounded by the curly braces. If you only need a variable in a catch-block, then it's scope is that catch-block and it should be declared in it.